# map showing gray on an Android Wear Emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, wear-os, google-maps-api-2, android-wear-data-api

i am using Android Studio, i created a wear AVD with API 22, Activated debugging on the device an obtained the google map API key, i used the example provided by google for a simple Wear application using Google Maps API :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/wear

project's files are provided here :

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/tree/master/AndroidWearMap

the application start but show a gray map without changes.

i think it is a problem of connectivity since the wear AVD is not connected to the internet like a Handled AVD so it can't download the map files.

i didn't try to connect the wear AVD with my Android Phone because the Android version it is using is not compatible with the Android Wear application required to connect a wear to Handled devices and and it doesn"t support higher versions.

is there a solution to let the wear AVD use my computer internet, or another way to use Google Maps on wear AVD ?

can i show the map correctly if i connect my wear AVD to a Handled Device ?

thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think emulator can't communicate automatically with hand device, i tried to implement the Data-layer API to transfer programmatically the map image (using static Maps) and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

To use Google Maps on Android Wear, it must be paired up with a phone. The phone is required to provide network access to download the map tiles.

Comment: i did but without result, i confirmed that the phone was paired by trying some notifications but when launching the map application there is nothing shown on the wear Emulator.

Comment: Have you checked the logcat output on both the phone and wearable to see if there are any error messages? There could be problems with the API key you used, and you need to have your signing key correctly added on the developer console.

Comment: yes i did, 
i dont think it is a problem of key since it works perfectly on Handled device,

Comment: after some searches and tries i think it is not possible to show Google Map on a wearable just by connecting the two devices via Android Wear App, 

i am trying to implements the Data Layer API to communicate the two devices and transfer the map from the handled to the wearable manually by using https map, even it is limited compared by Google Maps API

Comment: Please try the new API 23 emulator just released. I heard there were some problems with the API 22 emulator that were fixed, and the update may fix this problem.

Comment: yes i heard about the new API, you've right i will try with it, thank you.